# How to configure KOMA classes such that the bottom margin of a page equals its top margin?

Tags: margins, koma-script, typearea

I know that I could simply use the geometry package but is there a way to invoke that behaviour directly in the classes?

As far as I know, KOMA always tries to keep the bottom margin twice the size of the top margin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: No, there is no class-inherent way.

Longer answer: The KOMA-script classes use the `typearea` package to create page margins according to "construction by dividing" - see chapter 2 and especially sections 2.1 and 2.2 of the KOMA-script documentation for details. You may vary the divison factor and add a binding correction. Also (quoting from p. 37),

> there are cases where the text body
>   has to fit exactly some specified
>   dimensions. At the same time the
>   margins should be well spaced and a
>   binding correction should be possible.
>   The `typearea` package offers the
>   command `\areaset` for this purpose.

In other words, even when using `\areaset`, the bottom margin will be twice the size of the top margin.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is exactly the kind of answer I expected. I read in the documentation beforehand but I thought I had missed something. Thanks!