# KOMA-Script footer margins

Tags: margins, koma-script, geometry, typearea

I am doing one-page documents with title and I need more space so all text can be put on that page.  I achieve this by `\typearea{12}`.  What happens is that the footer margin gets *absurdly* large (say, 3 times side margins!).  I've tried to fix that using `\usepackage[bottom=10em]{geometry}`, however this command effects *all* margins and there is no gain.

Is there any way just to make the footer margin thinner?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\typearea{12}
\renewcommand*{\titlepagestyle}{empty}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}
\maketitle

A lot of text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with `geometry` settings that resemble those of `\typearea{12}` and change them as desired. There is no `KOMA-Script`/ `typearea` way to change only the bottom margin; see also [How to configure KOMA classes such that the bottom margin of a page equals its top margin?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17595/how-to-configure-koma-classes-such-that-the-bottom-margin-of-a-page-equals-its-t)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\renewcommand*{\titlepagestyle}{empty}

% Variant A: typearea, DIV=12
% \typearea{12}

% Variant B: geometry, resembling variant A
% \usepackage[scale=0.75,vmarginratio={1:2},heightrounded]{geometry}

% Variant C: geometry, larger vertical scale, larger ratio top:bottom margin
\usepackage[hscale=0.75,vscale=0.85,vmarginratio={2:3},heightrounded]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess it doesn't get better.  One would expect that KOMA package has one parameter that enables including more text on the same page following typographic rules...  Sometimes one just have to put all the text on one page.